# knockout / knockoutjs if statement is not working.. baffled by this

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

happy new year, and I have the following issue with knockoutjs if statement.

I have the following

```
  z.object = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap([{"Id":3,"Date":"2014"}]))

  <div data-bind="text: Date"></div>
```

above prints fine, 2014 but below if statement does not work.. what is going on?

```
 <!-- ko if: Date === 2014 -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

I am totally baffled by this.

Comment: have your tried `==` instead of `===`

Comment: Yes == does not work either. The only things that shows something happens within if is assign symbol = .. lol .. always true.

Comment: can you post the result of `ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap([{"Id":3,"Date":"2014"}]))`

Comment: That is the result ebram. I got it off my firebug.

Comment: The result is not showing, try to update your question with it

Comment: I meant that is what is shwoing in firebug. ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap([{"Id":3,"Date":"2014"}]))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44342/discussion-between-ebram-tharwat-and-novicedeveloper)

Comment: Try with `<!-- ko if: Date() == 2014 -->` if your Date property is an observable you need the `()`

Comment: Ok that seem to work.. I had tried it with === did not work, but == seems to work. add your response to answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons#359509):

The identity (`===`) operator behaves identically to the equality (`==`) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

So in your statement `Date === 2014`, here `Date` is tring and `2014` is number, then result is false.

Either convert string to number, number to string or use `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper i have tried `ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap([{"Id":3,"Date":"2014"}]))` but i got error `undefined is not a function`, does it work with you!?

Comment: Oh.. I forgot to say there is a foreach statement .. you need to wrap it in foreach and then access Date as it is an array.

Comment: so then you need to get refrence to the parent

Comment: I have .. that is why Date is as I print text: Date shows 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified example seems okay to me with ==, but not ===, please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cr2QT/2/

```
<div data-bind="text: Date"></div>

<hr>
<!-- ko if: Date == 2014 -->
<h1>Oogah Chaka (==)</h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<hr>
<!-- ko if: Date === 2014 -->
<h1>Chaka (===)</h1>
<!-- /ko -->

var viewModel = {
  Date: "2014"
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```